# Hyperledger Fabric generic put and get

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I have an interface that represents what I want to do with a blockchain.

```
public interface IBlockChain {

    /**
     * Put data on the blockchain
     *
     * @param key  the key being used to put the data on the blockchain
     * @param data the data being put on the blockchain
     */
    public boolean put(String key, Map<String, Object> data);

    /**
     * Get data from the blockchain
     *
     * @param key the key being queried
     * @return
     */
    public List<Record> get(String key);

    /**
     * Get all data from the blockchain
     * @return
     */
    public List<Record> all();
}
```

I have a working implementation for Multichain. But I'd now like to start on an implementation for other blockchain technologies.
How would I go about this in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0? Can I just push raw data to it? Or do I always need to call pieces of chain-code to create an object for me?

Comment: You have to call the Smart Contract (chaincode) that you have instantiated in your Blockchain. In your case, you would have a Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain. Then, there is a SDK (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node) that helps to call it. I don't know if I understood your question well. Could you give more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a chaincode to put and get the data.  The corresponding chaincode functions are:

```
PutState(key string, value []byte) error
GetState(key string) ([]byte, error)
```

There is a chaincode tutorial for Hyperledger Fabric v1.0:

```
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html
```

Then your client can call the chaincode and submit the transaction.  There is a Hyperledger Fabric Node.js SDK [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) that may help you better understand.